# What determines the label displayed in the "Kind" column of an OS X finder window and in search box labeled "Kind"?

Tags: macos, finder

What determines the label displayed in the "Kind" column of an OS X finder window and in search box labeled "Kind"?

For example, I use LaTeX, and all files with the extension .tex are labeled "LaTeX" in the finder Window and I have them set to open with SublimeText.

Did SublimeText set the file "Kind"?

Also, if I want to search for all file of type "LaTeX" the Finder search box only gives me a limited set of options for "Kind", e.g. Application, Archive, Document, etc. Can I change that option box to show "LaTeX".

Comment: This is not the right place for this type of question. You could post it in: [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Check `Ian C.`'s answer here... http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/49532/change-the-default-application-for-a-file-extension-via-script-command-line/49536#49536

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about "Ask Different". I'll go there and check out the answer linked.

Comment: This question was answered here.

http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193370/what-determines-the-label-displayed-in-the-kind-column-of-an-os-x-finder-windo/193375?noredirect=1#comment230490_193375